# VSCode Extension Clipboard Images

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to learn VSCode Extension development, I found that VSCode Extension doesn't seem to provide the function of Clipboard read or paste of images, although it does for text:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9a21b536639c2d986c50fb51b7da67bafdb50c9b/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L8292-L8308

Because I want to try to implement the Extension for pasting and uploading pictures in VSCode

What should I do if I want to paste and upload pictures stored in Clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

You could use URLs to image files instead of the images themselves. Either you have a file on disk and use it's location in the clipboard or you encode an image in a URL (by converting the data to base64 and appending that as URL parameter).